# minitest-reporters does not change minitest output style

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I have been trying to use the [`minitest-reporters`](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem to alter the output style of Ruby's builtin `minitest` testing library. However, it does not actually change the output.

It should be noted that I am not using Rails or Rake, but I didn't think that would make a difference. I am simply trying to test a Ruby command-line program that I have written.

Here's a dumb little test case (let's call it `dumbtest.rb`) that I was trying out:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/reporters'

Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(:color => true), Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new]

describe "MiniTest demo" do
  describe "when asked about the number 2" do
    it "should be equal to the number 2" do  
      2.must_equal 2
    end 
  end 
end
```

When I run the test, it just produces the default `minitest` output (i.e. colorless, no descriptions of passing tests, etc.):

```
$ ruby -Ilib:test dumbtest.rb 
Run options: --seed 48983

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001356s, 737.6595 runs/s, 737.6595 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

With `minitest-reporters` enabled, I expect the output to look something more like this (i.e. list both passing and failing tests as opposed to just failing, the word `PASS` is colored green, the final summary is color-coded, etc.):

[image]

There are no runtime errors. It's just not working for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried using just `Minitest::Reporters.use!`

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes, I have tried that as well. Still no change :/

Comment: you shoud use: `Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new]` to get the output you're looking for

Comment: Some problem in Rails 7 app